# Time series in Python up to microseconds

Tags: python, time-series

I would like to handle time series in Python.

It has been suggested to me that I use [scikit.timeseries](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/index.html) but I need to handle up to microseconds and this last, as far as I know, handles up to milliseconds.

Do you know any other library able to do that? At some point I need to merge 2 time series sampled at different times, and I would like to avoid rewriting such features or any new classes from scratch whenever it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `datetime` module handles microseconds:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.microsecond 
38672
```

Performing arithmetic operations against a `datetime` using a `timedelta` object returns a new `datetime` object:

```
>>> yest = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> yest
datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 9, 12, 37, 19, 38672)
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 10, 12, 37, 19, 38672)
```

Performing arithmetic operations against `datetime` objects returns a `timedelta` object.

```
>>> now - yest
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Comment: Hi jathanism. Thanks  for the response. I was more interested in some existing timeseries class. Do you know any?

Comment: Well, from what I know of a timeseries it is just iterating through a range of dates/times, correct?  It would be trivial to do something like: `for i in range(1,7): print now + datetime.timedelta(days=i)`. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [RedBlackPy](https://intuitionengineeringteam.github.io/RedBlackPy/).
You can read [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/redblackpy-fast-and-scalable-series-for-scientific-and-quantitative-research-in-python-cad49b5c6d3) with code examples. 
I think that RedBlackPy.Series is what you want (it is built for convenient work with time series). RedBlackPy is available for macosx and linux now.